# How do you implement a hierarchy of combo boxes with parent and child items?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

The title of this post could use some work, but I'm having trouble expressing myself without going into some detail.

So here goes.

I've got simple WPF application which retrieves lists of `State`, `City`, `Complex`, and `Building` from a third-party API.

```cs
public class State
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class City
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; } // FK to Id in State
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Complex
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; } // FK to Id in City
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Building
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; } // FK to Id in Complex
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

When populated with some data, these lists could look something like this;

```cs
StateOptions = new ObservableCollection<State>
{
    new State() { Id = 1, Name = "California"},
    new State() { Id = 2, Name = "New York"},
};

CityOptions = new ObservableCollection<City>
{
    new City() { Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "Los Angeles"},
    new City() { Id = 2, ParentId = 2, Name = "New York City"}
};

ComplexOptions = new ObservableCollection<Complex>
{
    new Complex() { Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "Los Angeles International Airport"},
    new Complex() { Id = 2, ParentId = 2, Name = "John F. Kennedy International Airport"}
};

BuildingOptions = new ObservableCollection<Building>
{
    new Building() { Id = 1, ParentId = 1, Name = "Terminal 1"},
    new Building() { Id = 2, ParentId = 1, Name = "Terminal 2"},
    new Building() { Id = 3, ParentId = 1, Name = "Terminal 3"},
    new Building() { Id = 4, ParentId = 2, Name = "Terminal 1"},
    new Building() { Id = 5, ParentId = 2, Name = "Terminal 2"},
    new Building() { Id = 6, ParentId = 2, Name = "Terminal 3"},
};
```

Using these lists the I need create a new object, `Foo`, which is then posted back to the API.

```cs
public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int StateId { get; set;
    public int CityId { get; set;
    public int ComplexId { get; set;
    public int BuildingId { get; set;
}
```

This is pretty simple in itself, as you could just put the lists in four observable collections, and use those as the `ItemSource` binding for four `ComboBox` elements. You could then use the `SelectedItem` binding property for each of these combo boxes to create your `Foo` object.

This would be neat if these were flat lists, but mind the `ParentId` field in the `City`, `Complex`, and `Building` models.

As such the four lists must be treating as a hierarchy. In fact, the name `ParentId` is quite misleading, as they're not referencing another entity of the same type. This becomes obvious when looking at the `Foo` class, which have foreign keys to all of the above.

Therefore I need to filter the items of a `City` combo box to only show items where the Id equals the ParentId of the SelectedItem of the `State` combo box. This is also the case for the `Complex` and `Building` combo boxes.

To add further to this, I would prefer solving this issue by creating a WPF User Control, as these four lists will appear again in many future views, and require the same functionality. I am however open to all solutions. I would also prefer doing this without making additional trips to the API, as the lists are quite big.

For your convenience I've created a demo project at https://db.tt/IAyOiq35. This project illustrates the problem by treating the four lists as flat, and as such you can select Los Angeles International Airport as the complex, even though New York was selected as the state. This is obviously wrong, and is exactly the kind of mistakes I want to prevent the user from doing.

Please leave a comment if you've got additional questions.

Comment: You can't filter the other lists (e.g. make a subset based on parentId) when you have selected an item in one list?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that would work alright, but as I see it that would push most of the logic into the view model. Trying to avoid this as this exact same logic would then be replicated over many future view models, and I like to avoid replicating code.

Comment: Build a hierarchical data model.

Comment: Can't you have lists inside of lists? Example: your state class having a List<CityOptions> property? and then CityOptions having a list of complex, and so long?

Comment: I am pretty sure this is also what Sheridan suggested. I can't modify the data objects retrieved from the API, so I would need to create four new classes, new mapping rules, and a method to build the hierarchical 
model. If i thought of this correctly, the end result in the view would be easily implemented using `SelectedValue`and `SelectedValuePath` on a `ComboBox`. Is this what you had in mind Sheridan and sexta13?

Comment: I am currently using four `Lookup` collections grouped by ParentId. As the user changes the selection of one list, i use `_cityOptions = _stateLookup [_selectedState.Id].ToList();` to change the list that the second ComboBox is bound to. This works as I expected, but I'm stilling looking for a way to move much of this logic away from my view models and into a User Control. It seems that creating a hierarchical data model might be the way to go for that.

Comment: Yes. That is the easiest way, because you pass all logic into the XAML, where you just have to say how to build...and set your datatemplates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a bit of discussion and some trial and error, we found a few ways to solve this issue.

In most cases the first solution would be sufficient, and probably recommended by most because it's easy to implemented with minimal logic in your view model, forcing the hierarchy in XAML.

However, I added two more solution as many might have considered these as well. In fact, we ended up adopting the third solution here, seeing as the first doesn't account for orphans unless you add each orphan as a child of each and every item.

**Solution 1 (Recommended)**

As sugguested by *Sheridan* you could build a hierarchical data model, making your `Node` into a `HierarchicalNode`. This is probably the easiest solution, and I would probably recommend going with this one if you can.

```cs
public class Node
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class HierarchicalNode
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    public List<HierarchicalNode> Children { get; set; }
}
```

From here you can bind your `List<TreeNode>` as the `ItemSource` of the first combo box. You'll then set the `ItemSource` of the second combo box to the `Children` property of the first combo box's `SelectedItem`. Add as many combo boxes as you have levels of children in your hierarchy.

**Solution 2**

Another solution would be to use `ILookup<int, HierarchyEntityBase>` in your view model, where `TKey` is `ParentId`. In your binding property for `SelectedItem` you would use that itemto build a new `ItemSource` for the child combo box by using that item's `ParentId` as the key in your lookup.

This works, but there's several issues with switching out a combo box's item source this way. For example you'll probably need to implement a way to remember selected values of a combo box before switching out its item source, and then try to find that item again in the new list of items.

**Solution 3**

None of the above solutions supported our particular use case, so this is the one we ended up implementing.

We had four tables where each row had an optional `ParentId` and a `ParentTableType`. In other words we would have a hierarchy of entities for some customers, while other had no hierarchy at all. This meant that the above solution wouldn't work very well, as it does not account for orphans.

The solution was to create a custom user control, `HierarchicalComboBox` that inherits from `ComboBox`. These would support entities of type `HierarchicalEntityBase` which amongst others had properties for `Id`, `ParentId`, and `ParentTableType`.

This new user control satisfied all my requirements, but it was quite a pain to implement.

The basic idea is to modify your `ItemSource` as the selection of a parent or child combo box changes. In cases where a parent combo box's selection changes, the child combo box must update its children and add its orphans accordingly. In some cases the user might start with the last combo box in your hierarchy, in which cases you must properly set the parent as the `SelectedItem` of each parent combo box, all the way to the top.

You'll best do this by implementing a dependency property to bind to the `ElementName` of the parent `HierarchicalComboBox`, and another dependency property to bind to a full list of entities of type `HierarchicalEntityBase` that should be used to look up items for the actual `ItemSource`.

The key to success for us was realizing that we needed a custom `Action` to replace the parent combo box's selection changed event, as that gave us the opportunity to conditionally trigger that action from the current combo box's selection changed event.

I won't go into details on the implementation, but feel free to drop a question if you're curious.